# Where is the difference between startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion and startRangingBeaconsInRegion

Tags: java, android, beacon, altbeacon

I don't understand the difference between the 2 methods in the BeaconManager class.

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconManager.html#startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion-org.altbeacon.beacon.Region

```
 beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconManager.html#startRangingBeaconsInRegion-org.altbeacon.beacon.Region-

```
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Javadocs it appears *startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion* simply looks for beacons that match the Region object. The *startRangingBeaconsInRegion* method on the other hand will look for beacons that match the Region object **and** will provide updates on the distance via RangeNotifier.

> **startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion:** Tells the BeaconService to start looking for beacons that match the passed Region object.
>
> **startRangingBeaconsInRegion:** Tells the BeaconService to start looking for beacons that match the passed Region object, and providing updates on the estimated mDistance every seconds while beacons in the Region are visible.

Comment: This is correct.  Monitoring gives you *one* callback each time all the beacons matched by the region definition appear or disappear.  Ranging gives you one callback every single second with a list of all beacons visible that match the region definition.

Comment: @davidgyoung and dymas, thank you guys. In addition to this question... when i want to add more regions. beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region1); 
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region2); beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region3); is this the right way?